# Can I change the role after the authentication is successful?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I successfully passed Github authentication with Spring Security OAuth2. However, the user role obtained through Github is USER_ROLE.

So I was wondering if I could modify the corresponding role by judging Github user information obtained after the authorization was successful in order to control the user's permissions.

For example, getPrincipal () to get a unique "name". Then modify the role by "name" (such as "ADMIN"). Finally, use @PreAuthorize ("hasRole ('ROLE_ADMIN')") to control permissions.

Or are there any other better solutions? I want to integrate Github's OAuth2 authorization and role-based rights management in this application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to obtain the current Authentication and create a new instance of it and set it on the SecurityContextHolder as described in Setting the SecurityContextHolder Contents Directly. Be sure you understand the implications of acting upon the Authentication in multiple threads (read on in the [reference to understand](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e1835)). An example of adding a GrantedAuthority to the current Authentication is given below:

```
// update the current Authentication
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(auth.getAuthorities());
authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl('ROLE_NEWROLE'));
Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordToken(auth.getPrincipal(),auth.getCredentials(),authorities)
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

Comment: UsernamePasswordToken is wrong. OAuth and other authentication methods are different. I finally solved by rebuilding the OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter and overriding the successfulAuthentication method.The key point is that the first step is to determine whether it is my Github account from the Principal after the authentication is successful. Then the current successful authentication OAuth2Authentication by SecurityContextHolder.getContext (). GetAuthentication () get. Then build a new Authentication and build a new OAuth2Authentication into SecurityContextHolder.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved by rebuilding the OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter and overriding the successfulAuthentication method.

The key point is that the first step is to determine whether it is my Github account from the Principal after the authentication is successful.

Then the current successful authentication OAuth2Authentication by SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() get. Then build a new Authentication and build a new OAuth2Authentication into SecurityContextHolder.

```
public class CustomOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
public CustomOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
    super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    if (authResult.getPrincipal().equals("cciradih")) {
        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request(), new Authentication() {
            @Override
            public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER");
            }

            @Override
            public Object getCredentials() {
                return oAuth2Authentication.getCredentials();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getDetails() {
                return oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getPrincipal() {
                return oAuth2Authentication.getPrincipal();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAuthenticated() {
                return oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication().isAuthenticated();
            }

            @Override
            public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {

            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return oAuth2Authentication.getName();
            }
        }));
    }
}
}
```